# Linear regression function runs into "nan is not defined" error

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, nan

I am trying to compute the linear regression of a stock price development for a specific time frame.  The code runs fine until I add the stats.linregress() function; giving me the following error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File
>   "C:/[...]/PycharmProjects/Portfolio_Algorithm/Main.py", line
>   3, in 
>   `from scipy import stats`
>
> File "C:[...]\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy__init__.py", line 61, in
>
> `from numpy import show_config as show_numpy_config`
>
> File "C:[...]\Python\Python35\site-packages\numpy__init__.py",line 142, in
>
> `from . import add_newdocs`
>
> File "C:[...]\Python\Python35\site-packages\numpy\add_newdocs.py",line 13, in
>
> `from numpy.lib import add_newdoc`
>
> File "C:[...]\Python\Python35\site-packages\numpy\lib__init__.py",line 8, in
>
> `from .type_check import *`
>
> File "C:[...]\Python\Python35\site-packages\numpy\lib\type_check.py", line 11, in
>
> `import numpy.core.numeric as _nx`
>
> File "C:[...]\Python\Python35\site-packages\numpy\core__init__.py", line 21, in
>
> `from . import umath`
>
> File "C:[...]\Python\Python35\site-packages\numpy\core\umath.py",line 30, in
>
> NAN = nan NameError: name 'nan' is not defined

I am using Python 3.5, Anaconda (for scipy and numpy) and PyCharm.

```
from yahoo_finance import Share
from math import log
from scipy import stats

yahoo = Share('YHOO')

date_list=[]
price_list=[]

timeframe = (yahoo.get_historical('2016-01-01', '2016-10-29'))
for item in timeframe:
    date_list.extend([item['Date']])
    price_list.extend([log(float(item['Close']))])

slope = stats.linregress(date_list, price_list)
print(slope)
```

When I run the example of the scipy user guide, I get the same error.
Example ([link](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.linregress.html)):

```
from scipy import stats
np.random.seed(12345678)
x = np.random.random(10)
y = np.random.random(10)
slope, intercept, r_value, p_value, std_err = stats.linregress(x,y)
print("r-squared:", r_value**2)
```

Does anyone know what could cause the error?

Comment: Looks like some numbers aren't filled in or something, so the prices are listed as nan (not a number). `linregress` presumably expects only numbers, so it throws an error. You're going to have to see what `Share()` is returning, and if it returns things that aren't numbers as well, you'll have to deal with that before regressing.

Comment: Please show more of the path to `umath.py`.  It would help to know which package is generating the error.

Comment: In fact, it would help to see the *complete* error message (i.e. the full traceback).  Copy and paste it into the question.

Comment: It sounds like you might have picked a bad name for one of your files, hiding some other module.

Comment: Hi - thanks for helping.

I have added the full error message. I am using dates for linregress as well. Do I need to convert the dates into numbers/floats?

Comment: I've checked the data coming from Yahoo. I see the same amount of dates and end of day prices. The dates skip each Saturday and Sunday (because no stock prices are recorded during the weekend).

Answer (score 0):

Here's your example, re-written to fix a few issues:

```
from yahoo_finance import Share
from math import log
from scipy import stats
from time import mktime, strptime
import numpy as np

yahoo = Share('YHOO')
timeframe = yahoo.get_historical('2016-01-01', '2016-10-29')
tpattern = '%Y-%m-%d' # Time-match-pattern

dates = np.zeros(len(timeframe))
prices = np.zeros(len(timeframe))

for ii,item in enumerate(timeframe):
    dates[ii] = mktime(strptime(item['Date'], tpattern))
    prices[ii] = float(item['Close'])

slope = stats.linregress(dates, np.log10(prices))
print(slope)
```

The `get_historical` method returns a list of `dict`, each containing strings. You need to convert your data to `float` to make it useful. This seems to be the main problem in your example.

Since you are pulling the data at the start and you know how many data points you will analyze, there's no reason to use lists as a data structure; `numpy` arrays are more efficient. Thus, use `dates` and `prices` rather than the lists.

With `numpy` arrays, it is more efficient to operate on the entire array of price data to generate the logarithm, rather than doing it one-at-a-time in the loop.

You probably intended the base-10 logarithm, not natural logarithm for your slope.

Comment: @dwilfling: Strange. I get the same results with Python2 and Python 3 (except for using print statement in Python2). Also, I get the same result on Windows and Ubuntu 16.04.:  LinregressResult(slope=6.8938424929225118e-09, intercept=-8.5328940373602329, rvalue=0.92426168485508664, pvalue=1.61357088610067e-88, stderr=1.9791154092032521e-10)

Comment: I just realized that you edited the question to include the full traceback, and that the example doesn't run. That indicates something is wrong with your installation. I suggest you remove and re-install Python3.